# Hover group of countries instead of single one on Amcharts 4

Tags: angular, typescript, maps, amcharts

this is my problem.
I grouped all countries of the map into regions (EMEA, NA, APAC, LATAM).
Now, on Hover, I’d like to highlight not the single country, but instead the entire region.

Do you have advice on how to do this?

This is my current code:

```js
his.regions[name] = this.map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
   this.regions[name].name = name;
   this.regions[name].useGeodata = true;
   this.regions[name].include = values;
   this.regions[name].mapPolygons.template.tooltipText = name;
   this.regions[name].mapPolygons.template.fill = am4core.color('#000000');
   this.regions[name].fill = am4core.color('#000000');

   const hs = this.regions[name].mapPolygons.template.states.create('hover');
   hs.properties.fill = am4core.color('#D0021B');
   this.regions[name].mapPolygons.template.propertyFields.fill = 'fill';
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've followed [the Map tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Multiple_polygon_series) pretty closely:

One method is to track the series' over/out events and set the appropriate states on their mapPolygons, this would allow granular control, e.g.

```
   this.regions[name].events.on("over", over);
   this.regions[name].events.on("out", out);

   function over(ev) {
     ev.target.mapPolygons.each(function(polygon) {
       polygon.setState("hover");
     });
   }

   function out(ev) {
     ev.target.mapPolygons.each(function(polygon) {
       polygon.setState("default");
     });
   }
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/pZOXpX

Or if you don't have a lot going on with SpriteStates, you can lean on the [`setStateOnChildren`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygonseries/#setStateOnChildren_property) boolean property of each series:

As it sounds, once a State is set on the series, its mapPolygons will trigger the same state key if they have it. Just have to create the hover state on the series in order for this to work:

```
   this.regions[name].states.create("hover");
   this.regions[name].setStateOnChildren = true;
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f28557342c2e59f4f834b342138281df/